# False labeling for on contours

Tags: qgis, raster

I loaded pressure NetCDF file then used geoprocessing->contour to draw contours instead of shaded colors but when I press label, there were wrong labeling despite I choose ELEV option. What is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! Could you please share an image of what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @Marwa Samy - Can you share the exact shapefile that you´re using to create the contours?